# execve() and environment variables

Tags: c, linux

I've got a question with how Linux process the environment varibales passed to execve():

Synoposis for execve():
**int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);**

Before calling execve(), we allocate the memory for holding envs/args from current process's memory mapping. But after execve(), all the text/data/bss/stack of the calling process are overwriten by the new program, and all the memory mappings of the old process are not preserved (including the memory for passed envs/args).

For the new program, where to read the envs/args? Does the kernel **make a copy** of the passed envs/args and placed it onto the new memory mapping, or some other tricks?

Comment: I guess that the new program can read the args from `argc` and `argv` in `main` function. I also guess that the program which calls `execve` will return from its main function and goes into the loader, in which the loader will set up all the environment and arguments as if the program is executed normally. **This is all guess so it might be totally wrong**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

When a process calls `exec`, the kernel copies the entire `argv` and `envp` arrays.  Then, these are copied into the new process image -- notably, when the program starts running, its stack looks like:

```
NULL
...
envp[1]
envp[0]
NULL
argv[argc-1]
...
argv[1]
argv[0]
argc
```

The Glibc startup code in `_start` massages this into the proper form to invoke `main`.

(For more details, the copy from the old process is done in [`linux/fs/exec.c`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=fs/exec.c;hb=HEAD), the copy to the new process is done in [`linux/fs/binfmt_elf.c`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=fs/binfmt_elf.c;hb=HEAD), and program startup is done in architecture-specific code such as [`glibc/sysdeps/i386/start.S`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/i386/start.S;hb=HEAD), [`glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/start.S;hb=HEAD), or [`glibc/ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S;hb=HEAD), which exist just to kick off into `__libc_start_main` in [`glibc/csu/libc-start.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/libc-start.c;hb=HEAD) which launches `main`.)

Comment: Nice job collecting all those links.